# How can i show the alphabet in a listview?

Tags: android, listview, show, indexer, alphabet

How can i show the alphabet like below:

[This is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7vKi.png)

I'm using alphabet indexer and that is works. But the alphabet missing from the right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android doesn't natively support showing the alphabet on the side of a ListView. To do this, you'll need a library. You'd probably want something like [this](https://github.com/woozzu/IndexableListView) or [that](http://hello-android.blogspot.com/2010/11/sideindex-for-android.html).

Answer (score 1):

**Use an `Adapter` that implements [SectionIndexer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html).**

And have your `ListView` have `setFastScrollEnabled(true)`.

Plenty of tutorials about that around the web, even Google samples I think.

Here is [a tutorial](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-listview-fastscroll/) I liked about SectionIndexer.

Comment: My code works exactly like this. But this is not shows the alphabet on the right side of the screen like on my picture. It just show one character if i scroll.

Comment: Yes, that is the Android way of doing it. What you ask is to port an iOS UI/UX design to Android...